# Opening a pdf file duplicates it on android

Tags: pdf

Whenever I open a pdf file in adobe reader in Android and then close it, the pdf file duplicates itself in the same folder. This happens again and again as I open and close the file.

I tried searching google but found nothing relevant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try to go to the pdf reader app settings and clean the data.
Settings -> apps -> the pdf app -> clear data 
This will reset the app.
Is this happening to different pds files or just one? Is the file located on the phone or on the internet?

Comment: Does clear data delete all files related to the app? I mean will any useful information be deleted like the pdf files? Also, strangely, this happens only to those pdf files which are stored in internal storage > download > adobe reader folder

Comment: Clear data will reset the app. This will delete any settings or preferences. It will show like when first installed.
It should not delete any folders like Downloads, so the pdf files should be safe.
This is either app related, which only the developer can handle, or in a worse case scenario, maybe one of those pdf files has some type of maleware appended to it. Again, worst case scenario. 
Make sure that you download files only from secure and reliable sources.
If you know they are safe and you can download them again, try also deleting them. See if this happens again when opened.